# Display a simple customer list in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

So Im currently copy/paste some code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/display-customers-in-list-learning-track

The code looks like this:

```
xaml:

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Customers}"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

About `x:Bind Customers`: it does not seem to autocomplete like it is wrong.

About `x:DataType="local:Customer"`: I get the error message `The name "Customer" does not exist in the namespace "using:helloUWP"`

```
cs:

namespace helloUWP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; }
= new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = "Name1" });
    }
}
```

}

I cannot build it. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the full source to be able to tell what namespace "Customer" is actually in and give you a proper answer, you can alternatively remove the `x:DataType` declaration entirely, and in the DateTemplate replace `{x:Bind ...}` with `{Binding ...}`

Comment: x:Bind is actually more effecient way to bind in uwp Binding consumes more resources @JohnnyWestlake

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the solution with a different architecture ( x86 or x64 ) becuse if Customer and MainPage are in namespace then your code should work.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake I´ve now edited my post with the full code

Answer (score 1):

To use a custom class in XAML, you first must declare the appropriate namespace in the root element, like for `Page`:

```
<Page ... xmlns:models="TheNamespaceWhereCustomerIs">
```

And then use:

```
x:DataType="models:Customer"
```

Comment: as it looks like the Customer is already in same namespace with MainPage, but ofcourse its my guess

Comment: In such case I am not sure would could be wrong :-D

Comment: the code looks fine, it looks a vs bug to me the wierd bug which sometimes gets solves with cleaning the solution :P